# displaying the map highlighting the provinces and some additional info

Tags: jquery

I am using PHP open source and I need the map of a country highlighting all the states in different colors. Once a particular state is hovered over, some info about the state needs to appear. Please suggest me how to do this. Is it possible to do this using some basic stuff ... I mean nothing like what goes beyond  my knowledge... Not sure if the tags that i have posted this query in is right...

Answer (score 0):

Try using html [image maps](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/imagemap.shtml) if you dont want to set the coordinates manually you can use a tool like dreamweaver so you can draw the shapes over the image and the application will create the coordinates for you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Google's Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/) - it has a map type chart, and allows active manipulations. Plenty of samples available. Be aware though that it is manipulated using JavaScript (client side) not PHP.

If you just want a static chart, look [here](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/map_charts.html).